# Does GridView Grouping supports ISupportIncrementalLoading

Tags: wpf, uwp

I want to implement incremental loading for my Collection Source which was bind to my `GridView`.

Does the `CollectionViewSource` supports `ISupportIncrementalLoading` interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the `LoadMoreItemsAsync` method won't get called for a grouped `CollectionViewSource`: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedbackdetail/view/773755/when-collectionviewsource-issourcegrouped-true-even-collection-implements-isupportincrementalloading-will-never-trigger-loadmoreitemsasync.

So despite the fact that the Source collection of a `CollectionViewSource` implements the `ISupportIncrementalLoading` interface, this is not sufficient to trigger data virtualization of a grouped `GridView`.

Comment: The workaround would be to set the Source of the CollectionViewSource to a non-grouped collection and style some specifc items to look like group headers.

Comment: @user5979 what did you end up doing? More options available now 2 years later?